# Parse string to date with specific culture only

Tags: .net

My question is kind of tricky, I hope you can understand what I'm trying to ask.

All my examples use the date 27th of february 2018.

In germany they write this date as 27.02.2018 or as 27.2.2018.

In the UK they write this date as 27/02/2018 or as 27/2/2018.

In the USA they write this date as 2/27/2018 or as 02/27/2018.

The ISO standard for this date is 2018-02-27.

In our software the user can enter a date in a string field and I like to check if the string the user entered is a valid date, but only in the local culture.
So in germany only 27.02.2018 or 27.2.2018 are valid entries, in the USA only
2/27/2018 or 02/27/2018 are valid entries.

To accomplish this I tried several methods (`CurrentCulture` is german)

1. `isValid = Date.TryParse("27.02.2018", New Date)`
2. `isValid = Date.TryParse("27.02.2018", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, New Date)`
3. `isValid = Date.TryParseExact("27.02.2018", "d.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, New Date)`

The first and the second way work, but they also recognize a date, when the user enters 2018-02-27.
The third way works the way I want it, but only when the user enters a german formatted date. If the user works on an american client and enters an USA formatted date, the third way would fail, since the second parameter is culture specific.

So, how can one parse a string to a date for the local culture and for the local culture only? Is there a built-in .NET way or do I have to write a parser myself, picking all the necessary information from the `CultureInfo`?

Answer (score 1):

I think `"d/M/yyyy"` is what you want, because `/` is replaced with the current culture's date separator. Read: [Custom date and time format strings: the "/" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier-1)

```
public static DateTime? TryParseLocalShortDate(string dtString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtString))
        return null;
    bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtString, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt);
    return isValid ? dt : new DateTime?();
}
```

Your sample:

```
DateTime? dt1 = TryParseLocalShortDate("27.02.2018"); // 27.02.2018
DateTime? dt2 = TryParseLocalShortDate("2018-02-27"); // null
```

---

> Unfortunately d/M/yyyy is recognizing "27.02.2018" and "27/02/2018" as
>   valid dates in german culture

Then you could use this approach using `DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` which is stricter:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseLocalShortDate(string dtString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtString))
        return null;
    string format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
    bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtString, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt);
    return isValid ? dt : new DateTime?();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `d/M/yyyy` is recognizing "27.02.2018" and "27/02/2018" as valid dates in german culture.

Comment: @Nostromo: have a look again

Comment: I already tried this `ShortDatePattern` as well, but this pattern in the german culture is `dd.MM.yyyy`, so it will recognize 27.02.2018 but not 27.2.2018.
My current approach is to check all `ShortDatePattern`s of the culture in question (`DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns("d"c)`) and return true, if one of the patterns fits. This kinda works, but I don't know if I want to go down that path.